# Installing SQL Server 2008 R2 on Windows 10 64-bit

Tags: windows-10, installation, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to install SQL Server 2008 R2 on a Windows 10 64-bit machine.

I get a message telling me that

```
This app might not be work correctly. 
Microsoft Sql Server (2008 and 2008 R2) isn't incompatible with this version of Windows.
```

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 1):

See [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/112208):

> SQL Server 2008 R2 is [not supported on Windows
>   10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2681562/using-sql-server-in-windows-8-and-later-versions-of-windows-operating).
>   This means the SQL Server team will not be releasing any security
>   updates or patches if they find any specific issues related to SQL
>   Server 2008 R2 code. There is no way to get updates automatically as
>   none would be released related to Windows 10.
>
> Having said that, SQL Server 2008 R2 installation is not blocked when
>   you try to install it on Windows 10. Of course, it is always better
>   and advisable to install the latest Service Pack (Service Pack 3 is
>   the final SP for 2008 R2).

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't need any solving, it will work with windows 10 but there might be some features that not since they are not 100% compatible, what you should do is use a newer version of SQL Server, one that is fully compatible with Windows 10.